# How to Float Left or Right Twice?

Tags: html, css

Basically, I want two different elements in the leftmost area of a div, and two for the rightmost area of a div.

However if I use float:left and float:right twice, I get the following:

```
   ELEMENT                                   ELEMENT

          ELEMENT                     ELEMENT
```

rather than

```
   ELEMENT                                    ELEMENT

   ELEMENT                                    ELEMENT
```

This is because, when I float for the second time the css floats for the remaining space left.

How do I fix this bug?

Comment: What do you mean by "float twice?" can you show us the CSS that's causing the issue?

Comment: Make sure you clear the floats every time you want to start a new line. Put this where you want to start a new line: <div style="clear: both;"></div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `clear:both;` with `float:left;` property.

Try **[Jsbin](http://jsbin.com/avugad/3/watch)** demo

```css
.left {
   float:left;
   width:40%;
   height:240px;
   border:1px solid red;
}

.right {
   float:right;
   width:40%;
   border:1px solid red;
   height:240px;
} 

.elem1 {
   float:left;
   margin-bottom:20px;
}

.elem2 {
   float:left;
   clear:both;
}

.elem3 {
   float:left;
   margin-bottom:20px;
}

.elem4 {
   float:left;
   clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
    <div class="elem1">element 1</div>
    <div class="elem2">element 2</div>
 </div>
 <div class="right">
    <div class="elem3">element3</div>
    <div class="elem4">element4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a `clear: both` in your CSS.

Your floats are working fine, but there is not enough content to push the next elements below the first elements.  If you set them to `clear`, then they will.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```css
.right {
    float:right;
} 

.left {
    float:left;
}​
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="right">1 element</div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    <div class="right">1 element</div>

    <div class="left">1 element</div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    <div class="left">1 element</div>
</div>
```

​
Here is the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/nQvEW/143/

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

Markup:

```
 <div class='clear:both'>
    <!-- left container -->
    <div style = "float:left;">
     <div style = "float:left;">
       Element
     </div>
     <div style = "float:left; clear:left;">
       Element
     </div>    
    </div>
   <!-- right container -->
   <div style = "float:right">
   <div style = "float:right;">
      Element
     </div>
   <div style = "float:right; clear:right;">
     Element
    </div>
</div>
```

Please use your own external style, this is just to guide you.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/L3SEJ/) on `jsfiddle`

```css
.wrapper {
   height:100px;
   border:1px solid red;
   margin: 5px;  
}

.left {
   margin: 10px;    
   float:left;
   width: 45%;    
}

.right {
   margin: 10px;
   float:right;
   width: 45%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">element 1</div>
    <div class="right">element 2</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">element3</div>
    <div class="right">element4</div>
</div>
```

[image]